# python .append influence other lists, bug

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

variable_a = ["aaa", "nnn", "ccc"]
variable_b = variable_a

for a in range(2):
    variable_a.append(random.randrange(10,50,1))
    print(variable_b)
```

#########output###########

['aaa', 'nnn', 'ccc', 33]
['aaa', 'nnn', 'ccc', 33, 22]

Variable b should output: ["aaa", "nnn", "ccc"]
Why variable b gets the same append items of variable a?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.copy()` method in order to create independent copy of a list type object. The `.copy()` method returns a new list. It doesn't modify the original list.

Possible solution is the following:

```
import random

variable_a = ["aaa", "nnn", "ccc"]
variable_b = variable_a.copy()   # << HERE

for a in range(2):
    variable_a.append(random.randrange(10,50,1))
print("variable_b: ", variable_b)
print("variable_a: ", variable_a)
```

Prints

```
variable_b:  ['aaa', 'nnn', 'ccc']
variable_a:  ['aaa', 'nnn', 'ccc', 12, 45]
```

**Follow the link for detailed information [Python - Copy Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_copy.asp)**